# Converting point to lat lon?

Tags: r, coordinate-system, peru, chile

I have received a shapefile with measurement points to be analyzed, but no matter how I try, I can't find how to convert to lat lon. I suppose it would be good to know the projection but when I look into the file (with R and summary()) it says "Is projected: NA" and "proj4string : [NA]".

One measurement-point I know is close to the border Peru-Chile has x,y = 354521, 7997417.8.

How can I find out how to convert this point (and many others) to lat lon?

I tried to follow the instructions of similar questions here, but to no avail.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like you are using R, so try the [proj4 package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proj4/). Using @mkennedy's guess of UTM zone 19S, you can query a [proj4string](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32719/proj4/), and use the package:

```
library(proj4)
proj4string <- "+proj=utm +zone=19 +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs "

# Source data
xy <- data.frame(x=354521, y=7997417.8)

# Transformed data
pj <- project(xy, proj4string, inverse=TRUE)
latlon <- data.frame(lat=pj$y, lon=pj$x)
print(latlon)
```

Produces:

```
        lat       lon
1 -18.10714 -70.37495
```

Also, if you need more precision in the output, set `options("digits"=12)`, and you will see more digits used to display the coordinates:

```
            lat            lon
1 -18.107144101 -70.3749500491
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on the coordinate values, it's probably UTM zone 19S (south). The question is what geographic coordinate reference system (datum) is being used. Try PSAD56.

Answer (score 0):

A northing of over 800,000 in Peru would be reasonable. IN the southern hemisphere, 0 northing is at the south pole and it goes up to just under 10,000,000 at the equator, where it starts over with 0 in the northern hemisphere. 
   If you can locate the correct eastings and northings of a dozen or so points, you could warp the whole thing to known coordinates (could get them perhaps from GoogleEarth - depends on the precision you want).