# Converting NZMG (or NZTM) to latitude / longitude for use with R map library

Tags: coordinate-system, r

I am a statistician with no background in GIS so apologies for the newbie question.

We routinely use R for a range of statistical and graphic analysis and are interested in using its map library to superimpose statistical graphics onto a map of New Zealand.  Drawing a map of New Zealand is easy, as is adding cities.  But as far as I can tell to project more data onto the maps I need latitude and longitude information.

I have a database of key locations of interest to us with grid references in NZMG or NZTM projections. I've found the technical instructions on converting to lat and long [here](http://www.linz.govt.nz/geodetic/conversion-coordinates/projection-conversions/projection-to-geographic-nzmg-to-nzgd1949), and conceivably could write code in R that applies this process.  But I've also found various web calculators that will do this for a specific point, so there must be relatively accessible software that does this automatically (I need to do it for about 2500 locations).

So, one version of my question is: how do I easily convert, in R or Excel, a list of NZMG or NZTM projections into latitude and longitude.

An alternative version of the question is: if I don't really need to convert them, is there some way I don't understand that the map projection packages in R can automatically project these locations onto a map?

Apologies again if I have missed some fundamental point.

EDIT / ADDITION after @whuber's helpful link to an almost identical question

Ok, so I've installed the proj4 library but yes I am having difficulty in specifying my proj4string.  If my understanding of [this page](http://www.maptoaster.com/maptoaster-topo-nz/articles/nztm/nztm.html) is correct the NZTM system is basically a universal transverse mercator based on WGS-84.  If I understand [this map](http://www.herpnet.org/herpnet/gbif/World_UTM_Map.pdf) correctly I should by in zone 60 (or 59, as they both cover New Zealand? but neither work anyway).  And if I understand proj4 properly the code below should be close.  One of those "ifs" must be wrong...

1781304 E 5485722 N is a "NZTM" coordinate in my database that should be a suburb of Wellington, in the south of the north island.

```
library(proj4)
library(maps)
library(mapproj)
proj4string <- "+proj=utm +zone=60 +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs "
p <- project(c(1781304, 5485722), proj=proj4string, inverse=T) # should be wellington
map('nz')
points(p[1], p[2], cex=5, pch=19, col=2)
points(-p[1], p[2], cex=5, pch=19, col=2) # In case I've misunderstood the sign. Appears on map but in the sea
```

Comment: It's nice to see you here, Peter.  Your question is answered at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18940/how-can-i-find-out-how-to-convert-this-point-to-lat-lon.  You may have follow-up questions, though, such as how precisely to specify the source and target coordinate systems as a "proj4string".  If not, please allow us to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, have added to the question - exactly that follow-up...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NZTM is not UTM zone 60 South. Its parameter values should be specified like this:

+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0.0 +lon_0=173.0 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000.0 +y_0=10000000.0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m

(it's not really WGS84, but NZGD2000 but close enough)

NZMG uses:

+proj=nzmg +lat_0=-41.0 +lon_0=173.0 +x_0=2510000.0 +y_0=6023150.0 +ellps=intl +units=m

NZMG is on NZGD 1949 which is not WGS84/NZGD 2000. That means a datum transformation. I believe you need to use cs2cs rather than +proj. There's some discussion [here](http://proj.maptools.org/gen_parms.html#towgs84) or [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms) and it's definitely been discussed before. A possible transformation uses these parameters:

+towgs84=59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993

Comment: Thanks, fantastic.  That works.  I only needed one of either NZTM or NZMG so I'm happy with the NZTM specification, which works great.

Comment: Do I simply append the +towgs84 transformation to the +proj string?

Answer (score 6):

One of the most overlooked aspects of [transforming coordinates from NZGD1949 to NZGD2000](https://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/coordinate-conversion/geodetic-datum-conversions/nzgd1949-nzgd2000), including NZMG1949 to NZTM2000, is that it should use a transformation method. There are three methods:

- 3 parameter similarity, with 5 metres nominal accuracy
- 7 parameter similarity, with 4 metres nominal accuracy
- Distortion grid, with 0.1 - 1.0 metres nominal accuracy

These are available to most GIS, including ArcGIS and PROJ-based. The [distortion grid](https://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/coordinate-conversion/geodetic-datum-conversions/nzgd1949-nzgd2000/nzgd1949) approach is clearly the best method, and can be used with a "nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb" grid shift file, available in PROJ's [proj-datumgrid-1.5.zip](http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-datumgrid-1.5.zip) (or newer). If building PROJ from source, this zip file needs to be unzipped to the `data` subdirectory before `./configure`.

The following PROJ.4 string is the correct one for [NZMG1949](https://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/datums-projections-heights/projections/new-zealand-map-grid-nzmg) (SRID=27200):

```
+proj=nzmg +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150 +ellps=intl +datum=nzgd49 +units=m +towgs84=59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993 +nadgrids=nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb +no_defs
```

For NZ coordinates, it's also a good idea to check them using [the LINZ Online Converter](https://www.geodesy.linz.govt.nz/concord/), otherwise you may have points that are hundreds of meters off.