# Projecting sp objects in R

Tags: r, coordinate-system

I have a number of shapefiles in different CRSs (mostly WGS84 lat/lon) that I'd like to transform into a common projection (likely Albers Equal Area Conic, but I may ask for help on choosing in another question once my problem gets better-defined).

I spent a few months doing spatial stats stuff in R, but it was 5 years ago.  For the life of me, I cannot remember how to transform an `sp` object (e.g. `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`) from one projection to another.

Example code:

```
P4S.latlon <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
hrr.shp <- readShapePoly("HRR_Bdry"), verbose=TRUE, proj4string=P4S.latlon) 
# Shapefile available at 
#   http://www.dartmouthatlas.org/downloads/geography/hrr_bdry.zip 
#   but you must rename all the filenames to have the same 
#   capitalization for it to work in R
```

Now I have a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` with appropriate projection information, but I'd like to transform it to the desired projection.  I recall there being a somewhat unintuitively-named function for this, but I can't remember what it is.

Note that I do not want just to change the CRS but to change the coordinates to match ("reproject", "transform", etc.).

**Edit**

Excluding AK/HI which are annoyingly placed in Mexico for this shapefile:

```
library(taRifx.geo)
hrr.shp <- 
  subset(hrr.shp, !(grepl( "AK-" , hrr.shp@data$HRRCITY ) |
                                     grepl( "HI-" , hrr.shp@data$HRRCITY )) )
proj4string(hrr.shp) <- P4S.latlon
```

Comment: Previous answer on projecting using the proj4 package [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18940/how-can-i-find-out-how-to-convert-this-point-to-lat-lon). Haven't tried this with SpatialPolygonsDataFrame though.

Comment: Actually looks like proj4 doesn't work with Spatial objects - but see answer below.

Comment: There's always the Spatial Task View: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html and my notes on Spatial Data [shameless plug]: http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~rowlings/Teaching/UseR2012/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the `spTransform()` methods in rgdal - using your example, you can transform the object to NAD83 for Kansas (26978):

```
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)

P4S.latlon <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
hrr.shp <- readShapePoly("HRR_Bdry", verbose=TRUE, proj4string=P4S.latlon)
plot(hrr.shp)
```

[image: unprojected]

```
hrr.shp.2 <- spTransform(hrr.shp, CRS("+init=epsg:26978"))
plot(hrr.shp.2)
```

[image: projected]

To save it in the new projection:

```
writePolyShape(hrr.shp.2, "HRR_Bdry_NAD83")
```

**EDIT**:
Or, as per @Spacedman's suggestion (which writes a .prj file with the CRS info):

```
writeOGR(hrr.shp.2, dsn = getwd(), layer = "HRR_Bdry_NAD83", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

---

If one is not certain which CRS to project from, refer to the following post:

- [Choosing the correct value for proj4string for shapefile reading in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64654/choosing-the-correct-value-for-proj4string-for-shapefile-reading-in-r)

And if one wants to define/assign a CRS when data doesn't have one, refer to:

- [Assigning CRS to shapefile when it doesn't have one, in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143579/assigning-crs-to-shapefile-when-it-doesnt-have-one-in-r)

Comment: note that writePolyShape DOES NOT write the .prj file! You should use writeOGR from rgdal (and use readOGR to read shapefiles) if you want to write and read the .prj file to set the CRS of your spatial objects in R!

Comment: Much better (edited accordingly) - thanks; hadn't realised it creates the .prj file! Awesome cheatsheet on your page, by the way.

Comment: It's strange how the projection in Mexico affects the appearance of the Alaska and Hawaii insets :-).

Comment: @whuber - hmm, yes ... someone's edited my posting which didn't have the actual maps in it showing those rather inappropriate insets ... never plotted 'em myself to see that they were there.

Comment: @Simbamangu Sorry, forgot that this .shp file rather inappropriately included the insets when I attempted to be helpful in adding the graphs!

Comment: Problem solved via subsetting.

Answer (score 8):

Since the introduction of the sf-package (have a look at the vignettes [sf1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf1.html), [sf2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf2.html), [sf3](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf3.html), [sf4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf2.html) and a migration guide [here](https://github.com/edzer/sfr/wiki/migrating)) you can use `st_transform()` for re-reprojecting your vector data:

```
require(sf)

hrr_sf = st_read('HRR_Bdry.shp', stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
    crs = 4326) # has +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84
plot(hrr_sf)

hrr_sf2 = st_transform(hrr_sf, "+init=epsg:26978") # 1st option sp::CRS() not working/ needed
hrr_sf2 = st_transform(hrr_sf, 26978) # 2nd option - EPSG code as an integer
plot(hrr_sf2)

# don't think about doing this:
hrr_sf3 = st_read('HRR_Bdry.shp', stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
    crs = 26978)

# Output layer
st_write(hrr_sf2, dsn = getwd(), layer = "HRR_Bdry_NAD83", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

sf will replace sp in the future and has due to its simplicity and speed imho several advantages compared to sp.