# Difference between raster() and readGDAL()?

Tags: raster, r, import

I am new in working with rasters and after having trouble working with them i'd like to know the difference between those two import functions.

for example i did this

```
  library(raster)
  s<-raster("random.TIF")
```

when trying to plot it, returns the correct image,
but  trying this:

```
s<-readGDAL("random.TIF")
```

returns a black image.

Comment: There are probably thousands of procedures working with rasters. You must narrow your question to one.

Comment: @Andre Silva Can you help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of these functions return a colored image, black or otherwise. This

```
library(raster)
s <-raster("random.TIF")
s
```

Returns a `RasterLayer` object (or perhaps a RasterBrick if there are multiple layers in "random.TIF"). This class (type of object) is defined in the raster package. You can visualize it with

```
plot(s)
```

This

```
library(rgdal)   
x <- readGDAL("random.TIF")
class(x)
```

Returns a `SpatialGridDataFrame`. This class (type of object) is defined in the sp package. You probably did  `plot(s)` but that does not work well as that would probably show a 'black image'. An appropriate way to plot a SpatialGridDataFrame is

```
spplot(x)
```

sp and raster objects play well together, but they are different. A possible starting point is reading this: cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/Raster.pdf