# Standardizing layers in R?

Tags: r, scale-factor

I am using R to develop species distribution maps.
Since I standardized my covariates during the modeling process, I needed to transform the country-wide data (i.e. riv) using the same values.

I read in my layer as a tiff with readGDAL.
I used the function attribute to obtain the following values.

However, I got the following error when I tried to transform the country-wide data.

> Error in riv - 0.19 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Anybody know why this is not working?

```
riv <- readGDAL("stackkazc10a_Clip.tif") # layer to be standardized
sc.s # data set for the scaled variables
attributes (sc.s)
#$`scaled:center
riv
0.1981767
#$`scaled:scale
riv
0.2406652
riv.s <- (riv-0.1981767)/0.2406652
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `readGDAL` to load a `.tif` file, therefore it produces a `SpatialGridDataFrame`, see also in [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144194/difference-between-raster-and-readgdal) about the difference from `raster`.

The error means you are trying to use a binary operator (`-`, `+`, etc.) to a non-numeric, non-number variable (see this [stack-overflow thread on a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665428/non-numeric-argument-to-binary-operator-error-in-r)). In your case this would be the `SpatialGridDataFrame` class which should be of type `list`. Retrieving  `riv@data`, assumming some numeric data in you `.tif` attributes would solve it.

However, I prefer to use `rasterLayer` class which can be used with binary operators directly.:

> `library(raster)
>   riv <- raster("stackkazc10a_Clip.tif")`

Alternatively, you can use your code, but note that to access the data sloe of a class `SpatialGridDataFrame` you could try either `riv@data` or any of the coercion methods available for this class, e.g. `as.matrix`, `as.array`, also note that `[` (subset) of specific row, cols should extract attributes. See class information [here](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/rforge/sp/man/SpatialGridDataFrame-class.html).