# Error While Converting UTM data to Lat-Long Coordinate

Tags: coordinate-system, r, utm, sp

I have a a dataset of Vancouver,BC where Coordinate values are projected in UTM Zone 10 . Now  I can convert it using spTransform by the following piece of code and looks like the it correctly transforms the coordinates ,as I can see if I plot them in a map .

```
cord_transform <- function(df){
  coordinates(df) <- ~X+Y 
  proj4string(df) <- "+proj=utm +zone=10 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"
  df.lat.long <- spTransform(df,CRSobj=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
  df.lat.long


}
```

However  I realized I dont need a SPdataframe ,rather my purpose serves if I can transform the UTM coordinates in lat -long coordinates in the original data.table (since the data is huge I want to use data.table ) but when I follow  [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18940/converting-point-to-lat-lon) answer,and write a similar code for the data.table

```
func <- function(x,y){
  proj4string <- "+proj=utm +zone=10 +ellps=GRS80 +units= m + no_defs"
  inp <- list("x"=x,y="y")
  print(inp)
  pj <- project(inp,proj4string,inverse = TRUE)
  print(pj)
  latlon <- list(lat = pj$y,lng = pj$x)
  latlon



}
crime.data.2016.jan[,c("lat","lng"):=func(X,Y)]
```

I get this error :

```
Error in project(inp, proj4string, inverse = TRUE) : 
  unknown unit conversion id
```

a subset of the data looks like this :

```
         NEIGHBOURHOOD        X       Y
 1:       Renfrew-Collingwood 497445.9 5454283
 2: Central Business District 491580.1 5458745
 3:                           492757.5 5458792
 4:              South Cambie 491371.1 5455550
 5:                  West End 490417.0 5459169
 6:               Shaughnessy 489926.6 5454845
 7:                   Marpole 490409.0 5450869
 8:            Mount Pleasant 492545.4 5456743
 9:                  Fairview 490767.8 5456820
10:                 Kitsilano 488624.5 5457182
11:                 Killarney 497326.3 5452640
12:          Hastings-Sunrise 496763.8 5458220
13:  Kensington-Cedar Cottage 494917.4 5455246
14:                Kerrisdale 488711.0 5452722
15:       Victoria-Fraserview 495207.1 5452375
16:                Strathcona 493345.6 5458515
17:         Dunbar-Southlands 486589.5 5454941
18:                  Oakridge 490997.4 5453021
19:                    Sunset 492937.0 5451823
20:             Arbutus Ridge 488145.0 5455054
21:        Grandview-Woodland 494940.8 5458213
22:                Riley Park 492607.3 5455102
23:           West Point Grey 485649.1 5456957
24:              Stanley Park 490531.0 5460906
25:                  Musqueam 485508.0 5453015
                NEIGHBOURHOOD        X       Y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string has wrong spaces:

```
proj4string <- "+proj=utm +zone=10 +ellps=GRS80 +units= m + no_defs"
```

should be

```
proj4string <- "+proj=utm +zone=10 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"
```

Comment: Hi , if I change it runs without error but introduces NAs

`Warning messages:`
`1: In project(inp, proj4string) : NAs introduced by coercion`
`2: In project(inp, proj4string) : y is shorter than x, recycling`

Comment: When I changed `inp <- list("x"=x,y="y")` from a list to a dataframe it worked like a charm . Thanks .